# Accessing a function of an instance which is in an arraylist

Tags: java, oop, class

I'm tring to access a function of an instance which is in an arraylist. **Is there any way to do that without using the class name** of the instance?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class apple {
    int price;

    public void myFunction(int iPrice)
    {
        price=iPrice;
    }
}

class orange {
    int price;

    public void myFunction(int iPrice)
    {
        price=iPrice;
    }
}

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List list= new ArrayList();

        //create 3 apple object to list
        list.add( new apple() );
        list.add( new apple() );
        list.add( new orange() );

        list.get(0).myFunction(1); /* Error: The method myFunction(int) is undefined for the type Object*/

    }
}
```

I know that;`((apple) list.get(0)).myFunction(1);` is a way but **I'dont want to use any class name** while calling the function.

Comment: You need to learn OOP design concepts.

Comment: I have tried to explain you [before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11073990/creating-instance-list-of-different-objects-and-using-these-objects/11074074#11074074). Why you don't asking what are you don't understanding?

Comment: @alaster you are wrong, you tried to explain it to "mypolat", this time OP is "fadeir" ^_^

Comment: why do you want to have multiple different objects in the same list? Better yet: why do you not want to use class names to explicitly state from which class or object you are referring, this goes against OOP

Comment: @Pshemo and fadeir can't start a bounty to that question because of 1 reputation :)

Comment: You can put any object without your method in list. Why you think you can call this method for any object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use generics, together with an `abstract` class or an interface:

```
abstract class Fruit {
    public abstract void myFunction(int price);
}

List<Fruit> list= new ArrayList<Fruit>();
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes - you'll need to use *generics*, and interfaces.

The reason you need to "use" the class name at the moment is that Java is strongly typed.  You can't call a method on an object, unless the object's type exposes such a method.  As it is at the moment, when you get something out of a `List` it can be of any type - so the Java compiler can't be sure that `list.get(0)` is something that **has** a `myFunction` method.

So you use generic parameters to the list, to restrict what types of objects can be added.  This way, when you retrieve an object it's of a known type, and so appropriate methods can be called.  So - what type of objects does your list hold?  Well, it's "fruits", but you don't have a concept for this yet.

So you can define an *interface* in order to describe "something that implements these methods".  Let's define it like so:

```
public interface Fruit {
    void myFunction(int iPrice);
}
```

That's all there is to it.  You'll need to change your definition of the classes to declare that they do indeed implement this interface (it's not automatic):

```
class Apple implements Fruit {
    // rest as before
    // ...
}
```

and the same for `Orange`.  **Now** you can declare that your list holds `Fruits`, and when you get something out you can be sure it's a `Fruit`.  And so you can call `myFunction(int)` on it.

So in the main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Fruit> list= new ArrayList<Fruit>();

    //create 3 apple object to list
    list.add( new Apple() );
    list.add( new Apple() );
    list.add( new Orange() );

    list.get(0).myFunction(1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you ask for is not possible in Java, not without reflection, that is. Or with a framework built on top of it, like an expression language parser. Java is a statically typed language, and the compiler won't let you call a method he doesn't see.

An alternative you could consider is the use of interfaces.

```
public interface Fruit{
    void doSomething(int i);
}
```

Now let both implementations implement that and you can call the method without knowing which class it is.

Answer (score 2):

Since the answers that were given until now only cover solutions but not explain WHY that works i put it into very simple words for you what really happens behind the scenes:

There can be an arbitrary object in that list. This means, it could be an object without the method `myFunction()`.

No, think of an class definition as a contract. If you generate a new Object of type apple like so

```
Apple apple = new Apple();
```

you are saying "I want a new object, that obeys all conventions of the type 'apple' and i want it to be a new apple".
so, the compiler knows that your `Apple` type **has to have** that function, so you can call

```
apple.myFunction()
```

.
But if you are saying

```
Object o = new Apple();
```

you are saying "i want a new object that obeys all conventions of the type 'object' and i want it to be an apple". You can do that, since all classes implicitly exent java.lang.Object, so  a new Apple() is also a new object.
But if you are tring to invoke

```
o.myFunction()
```

then the compiler says "Whoops, not possible. 'o' obeys all conventions of 'Object' and everything else is optional. And the contrct i have here for an Object does not include a method named myFunction".

Now, the same happens with your List. You are creating a list of *Objects*. The compiler only knows for certain that there are objects in this list - but can not make other assumptions.

you can, however, force the compiler to **treat** this specific object as an Apple by casting it using (Apple).

Another way to solve that would be by using generics, this means, by creating a `new ArrayList<Apple>`. This way you could only store apples in that list and list.get(x) would return an object that is **known** to conform to the standards for an Apple.

Now, if you create an interface *Fruit* that defines a method `myFunction` and create subclasses Apple, Banane and what so ever that implement Fruit. you can create a List of type Fruit and store both Apples and Bananas in it and easily call list.get(x).myFunction(), since every object in that list **has to be** a Friut and therefore **has to have** the method myFunction().

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is not best solution, but you can cast `list.get(0)` to `apple`:

```
if (list.get(0) instanceof apple)
{
    ( (apple)list.get(0) ).myFunction(1);
}
```

Comment: That's a great suggestion however OP said he didn't want to use the class names explicitly. But depending on his reason this is a viable solution!

Comment: @DavidKroukamp I disagree, to me the OP has explicitly asked for a way around this.

Comment: yes but what i ment was he said "I'dont want to use any class name while calling the function" but hey thats just technically. Hence why I asked the OP what he wants to do and why he 'doesnt' want to use them

Answer (score 0):

If you really cant/don't want to use generics/casting/extending abstract class Fruit you can always try reflection :)

```
    List list = new ArrayList();

    // create 2 apple and 1 orange to list
    list.add(new apple());
    list.add(new apple());
    list.add(new orange());


    Object o=list.get(0);
    // if class of "o" object contains method "myFunction" we can call
    // it this way
    try {
        o.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("myFunction", int.class).invoke(o, 1);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException
            | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException
            | InvocationTargetException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```